# Modifying session is not saving

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using nodejs 8.9.3 and express 4.15.5.

What I'm doing is trying to save user information into `req` at the time of logging in. After authentication is successful, I *re-specify* user variables. Then once that is done, when I access i.e. `'/dashboard'` the user information is not stored.

**What I've attempted**

- Changed express-session items like saveUninitialized, resave, and rolling to true / false, with different combinations.
- req.session.save() in the login middleware
- Changed login response from a `res.send(stuff)` to `res.redirect('/dashboard')`
- Tried to store user in `req.session.user` instead of `req.user`

I've had absolutely no luck in attempting to get this to work.

**app.js**

```
...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'javascript',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    rolling: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,  // 30 days
        secure: process.env.NODE_env === 'production', // currently false as NODE_env is development atm
    }
}));
...
// Load routes
require('./routes/auth.js')(app);
```

**auth.js**

```
let userPre = {
    dn: '',
    userPrincipalName: '',
    sAMAccountName: '',
    displayName: '',
    pwdLastSet: '',
    memberOf: [],
    isAuthenticated: false
};

module.exports = (app) => {
    let user = function(req, res, next) {
        req.user = userPre;
        next();
    };
    app.use(user);
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('login', {title: 'Login'});
    });

    app.post('/api/login', async(req, res) => {
        await ad.user(req.body.userName).authenticate(req.body.password)
            .then(async(authResponse) => {
                if (authResponse === true)  {
                    return await ad.user(req.body.userName).get();
                }
                else if (authResponse === false) {
                    res.send('failed');
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .then(userProfile => {
                if (!userProfile) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    req.user = {
                        dn: userProfile.dn,
                        userPrincipalName: userProfile.userPrincipalName,
                        sAMAccountName: userProfile.sAMAccountName,
                        displayName: userProfile.displayName,
                        pwdLastSet: userProfile.pwdLastSet,
                        memberOf: [],
                        isAuthenticated: true
                    };
                    userProfile['groups'].forEach(group => req.user.memberOf.push(group.cn));
                    if (req.user.memberOf.filter(obj => obj === 'Cat')) {
                        // authentication is successful and now I want to redirect to dashboard with req.user still being set.
                        // Tried req.session.save() here as well.
                        console.log(req.user); // Data has been set
                        res.redirect('/dashboard');

                    } else {
                        res.send('success') // ignore
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });

...

    app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.user); // all variables are still ''.
        res.render('dashboard', {title: 'Dashboard'})
    });

...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there all you have to do is store the user in the `req.session.user` not on the `req.user`.

```
req.session.user = {
    dn: userProfile.dn,
    userPrincipalName: userProfile.userPrincipalName,
    sAMAccountName: userProfile.sAMAccountName,
    displayName: userProfile.displayName,
    pwdLastSet: userProfile.pwdLastSet,
    memberOf: [],
    isAuthenticated: true
};
```

Comment: Wow. That makes a lot of since now. I got it working by modifying it with your method. Thank you very much.